# use a variable from a store to another store returns undefined (pinia)

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, local-storage, pinia, nuxt3

hi i'm using nuxt in my app and pinia for store and i want to extract user id from a jwt access code in a store called userStore and i want to post that user id in another store called blogStore and when i want to access to that user id from blogStore that returns undefined and here i extract that data from localStorage and works fine:

```
    import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
    import {reactive , ref} from 'vue'
    import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

    export const useUserStore = defineStore('User' , () =>{

    if(!process.client) return;

    
    let isAuthenticated = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated"))
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")) : null
    
    let userInfo = token ? jwtDecode(token.access) : null
    
    console.log(userInfo.user_id) // output = number for example 24

 

    return { userInfo , token , isAuthenticated }
   })
```

and here when i want to log that or store it to a variable that returns undefined:

```
   import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
   import {reactive , ref} from 'vue'
   import { useUserStore } from '@/store/user'
   import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'

    export const useBlogStore = defineStore('Blog' , () =>{
       const server = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"

       const userStore = useUserStore()
    
       const userID = userStore.userInfo.user_id


       const blog = reactive({
             user: userID,
             title: 'first blog',
             body: 'some random text'
       }) 


     console.log(blog)
    // output is = {user: undefined , title: 'first blog' , body: 'some random text'}

       const creatBlog = async () =>{
            const sendData = await fetch(server+"/api/create-blog/" , {
               method: 'POST',
               headers:{
                "Content-Type":'application/json'
               },
               body: JSON.stringify(blog)
            })
            const res = await sendData.json()
       }


       return { userId , creatBlog }
   })
```

Comment: Note that the early return in your user store setup (i.e. `if(!process.client) return;`) is going to kill the store for all subsequent calls. But if `userStore.userInfo.user_id` is undefined, `userStore.userInfo` has to be an object, so it is a different problem.

Comment: @MoritzRingler  - I already tried this but didn't work